# Continuous integration for Windows 8 Store Application with Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, service, jenkins, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make a continuous integration on a Windows Store Application with Jenkins. Jenkins is installed on a Linux machine (due to other project like iOS and Android). In order to manage Windows project I installed a build machine on Windows 8 64 bits Pro (WP8 project are build on this machine). I want to use this machine for my WIndows Store Application.

At the beginning, I built my project with msbuild (used to generate the AppPackages folder). Then I accept the certificate (.cer) with

```
CertUtil -addstore root <FILE.cer>
```

After that, I tried to use vstest.console.exe on the application (.appx). This executable needs to run in an interactive service, so I launched it with another exe, which get access on the interactive session and launch vstest.console.exe (I made this executable with this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110568/Alternative-way-for-Window-services-to-interact-wi ).

Despite that, vstest.console.exe failed with that message:

```
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.60315.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
Error: Failed to launch test executor for the Windows Store app with error code 0.
```

When I run my script, without using the Jenkins service (or a service built by me) it works perfectly. Used for a Windows 8 Phone, the script for testing the project works perfectly, but doesn’t when used for Windows 8 Metro application.

Has anyone managed to run unit tests from a service?

Comment: A) Are you running the command line as administrator? B) Do you have a Developer's License installed and current? C) Make sure that you're running `vstest.console.exe` with the `/InIsolation` switch, as outline [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/05/06/running-unit-tests-for-windows-metro-style-apps-from-command-line.aspx).

Comment: A) I run the command line as administrator.
B) I have a developer's license intalled and current on the build machine
C) I run vstest.console.exe with /InIsolation.

Did you manage to launch vstest.console.exe from a service on a Windows Store project?

Comment: I have not yet had a chance to try, no. One of my friends has used TFS for continuous integration, but I generally been doing my unit tests manually. Have you tried it with both 32-bit vstest.console.exe and 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, I have tried 32-bit and 64-bit. I know TFS can make that but TFS is not free...

Answer (score 1):

We also use Jenkins for Windows Store App CI by launching and MSBuild job. Maybe this snippet will help you?

```
<Target Name="UnitTest" DependsOnTargets="PreTest;Compile" Condition="'$(SkipTests)'=='' and '$(Platform)'=='x86'" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <TestAppx Include="$(SolutionDir)\**\*x86*\**\*Tests*.appx" />
        </ItemGroup>

    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running tests for %(TestAppx.Identity)" />
            <Exec Command='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" %(TestAppx.Identity) /InIsolation /platform:x86 /Logger:trx /UseVsixExtensions:true'
                  WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionDir)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: What are the server requirements? Does it have to be a Win 8 server or can it also be an Windows 2012 (R2)? Maybe you also know if we could do Win Phone 8 on a Windows 2012 Server...